# unable to load images of my iOS application on device

Tags: ios

In my iOS application, i have some images, when running the app on simulator, images are displayed but when running it on iPod, the images are not displayed. what is the reason? tell me please...

Comment: You need to add more info/code for folks to help you ...

Comment: actually i stored images in core data from sqlite database browser and i'm retrieving them from database to show them in image view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% chance of occurrence of this issue is due to the filenames. YOU MUST USE THE EXACT FILENAME (CONSIDERING UPPER/LOWER CASE OF ALPHABETS) IN YOUR CODE AS IT IS IN YOUR RESOURCES.

e.g. in resources you have "MyImage.png" if you specify `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];` it will work on simulator - no problems but it will not work on device. for device, you must use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];` to make it work.

Best of luck!!

Comment: actually i stored images in core data from sqlite database browser and i'm retrieving them from database to show them in image view, if names are incorrect even i can't view them in simulator

Comment: you are correct, my image name is image.PNG but in database i stored it as image.png, the reason that it works in simulator is simulator is case insensitive when it comes to device, it is case sensitive..

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your app file (.app)select unarchived it and see image file name in folder. May it will differ from your name (Upper/lower case).

Comment: you are correct, my image name is image.PNG but in database i stored it as image.png, the reason that it works in simulator is simulator is case insensitive when it comes to device, it is case sensitive..

Comment: I am trying to access the images from ImagePicker(library images). Also, for exact naming thing i am using:


 UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

 but still random crashes are there with the same reasons.